# Hanging query in Postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have an issue with a `postgresql-9.2` DB that is causing what is effectively a deadlock of the entire DB system.

Basically I have a table that acts as an operation queue. Entries are added to the table to indicate the need for an operation to be done. Subsequently one of multiple services will update these entries to indicate that the operation has been picked up for processing, and eventually delete the entry to indicate that the operation has been completed.

All access to the table is through transactions that first acquire an transactional advisory lock. This is to ensure that only one service is manipulating the queue at any point in time.

I have seen instances where queries on this queue will basically lock up and do nothing. I can see from `pg_stat_activity` that the affected query is `state = active`, `waiting = false`. I can also see that all requested locks for the `PID` in `pg_locks` have been granted. But the process just sits there and does nothing.

Typically I can precipitate this by repeated mass addition and removal of (several hundred thousand) entries to the queue. All access has to go through the advisory lock, so only one thing is getting done at a time.

Once one of these queries locks up then other queries pile up behind it, waiting on the advisory lock - eventually exhausting all DB connections.

The query that locks up is typically a deletion of all entries from the queue (delete from `queue_table;`). I have, however, seen one instance where the query that locked up was an update of several tuples within the table.

Right now I don't see anywhere where I could be deadlocking against any other transaction. These are straightforward inserts, deletes and updates. No other tables are involved (accept during addition of entries where the data is selected from other tables).

Other pertinent facts:

All access to the table is in fact through a view (can't access the table directly which is why i'm using an advisory lock instead of an exclusive lock on the table or similar).

The table is logged (which is probably a really bad choice in this case, i'm going to try using an unlogged table next week).

I usually also see an autovacuum (analyze) operation, also active, also waiting = false and also apparently locked up. I presume the autovacuum is coming along to re-optimize after my mass additions / removals.

Looking for any suggestions of what else I might look at to debug this issue when I next reproduce it. I'm kind of starting to feel that this might be some kind of performance optimization / DB configuration related issue.

Any suggestions of things to look at would be most welcomed!

Comment: It might be worth thinking about the underlying data storage (hdd, vmware volume, SAN); operations waiting on I/O look like they're idle because they use no CPU. Also check stats to see if table is ever being successfully vacuumed - autovacuum will abort if it can't lock, so high number of writes can lead to ridiculously bloated storage and indexes.

Comment: _But the process just sits there and does nothing_: can you `strace` the server process?

Comment: Strace sounds like a good plan. If and when the problem re-occurs, i'll get a trace.